# How to fix audit lighthouse suggestions for Improved performance

Tags: javascript, audit

I ran an audit in chrome for a web application I am developing for udacity mobile web specialist project and I am getting a score of 85 for performance.
I need to get a score of 90 and above to pass the project.

Here are the diagnostics -

1. **Uses inefficient cache policy on static assets 14 assets found**

   *A long cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page.*
2. **Has significant main thread work 6,520 ms**

   *Consider reducing the time spent parsing, compiling and executing JS. You may find delivering smaller JS payloads helps with this.*
3. **JavaScript boot-up time is too high 3,810 ms**

   *Consider reducing the time spent parsing, compiling, and executing JS. You may find delivering smaller JS payloads helps with this*

Here is part of my service worker script. -

```
importScripts("/js/idb.js");
importScripts("/js/dbhelper.js");
const staticCacheName = 'restaurant-1';
const resourcesToCache = [
'/',
'index.html',
'restaurant.html',
'css/styles.css',
'js/idb.js',
'js/dbhelper.js',
'js/restaurant_info.js',
'js/main.js',
'sw.js',
'img/1_small.jpg',
'img/1_medium.jpg',
'img/1_large.jpg',
'img/2_small.jpg',
'img/2_medium.jpg',
'img/2_large.jpg',
'img/3_small.jpg',
'img/3_medium.jpg',
'img/3_large.jpg',
'img/4_small.jpg',
'img/4_medium.jpg',
'img/4_large.jpg',
'img/5_small.jpg',
'img/5_medium.jpg',
'img/5_large.jpg',
'img/6_small.jpg',
'img/6_medium.jpg',
'img/6_large.jpg',
'img/7_small.jpg',
'img/7_medium.jpg',
'img/7_large.jpg',
'img/8_small.jpg',
'img/8_medium.jpg',
'img/8_large.jpg',
'img/9_small.jpg',
'img/9_medium.jpg',
'img/9_large.jpg',
'img/10_small.jpg',
'img/10_medium.jpg',
'img/10_large.jpg',
'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css',
'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js'
];
```

For 2 and 3. - Whenever I try to compress or minify my javascripts, I always get error like - Unexpected token:. 
I know for sure the js isn't having errors.

How can I fix these so I could get a perfomance score of 90 or above ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to change part of my service worker code (sw.js)

from

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
event.respondWith(
caches.match(event.request, { ignoreSearch: true }).then(response => {
  return response || fetch(event.request).then(res => {
    return caches.open(staticCacheName).then(cache => {
      cache.put(event.request, res.clone());
      return res;
    })
  });
})
);
});
```

to

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
event.respondWith(
caches.match(event.request, { ignoreSearch: true }).then(response => {
  return response || fetch(event.request).then(res => {
    if (!res || res.status !== 200 || res.type !== 'basic') {
      return res;
    }
    return caches.open(staticCacheName).then(cache => {
      cache.put(event.request, res.clone());
      return res;
    })
  });
})
);
});
```